# Windows Forms WebBrowser control in different target platform

Tags: c#, winforms, highcharts, webbrowser-control

I wrote a simple application that displays the web page using WebBrowser control.
If application compiled with target platform Any CPU/x64 chart on page looks like this:

[image]

If target platform is x86:

[image]

Why this is happening? Charts created with Highcharts

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels to find help.

Comment: very nice question, you are not appreciated as you should be... sorry i don't have an answer, i'll search for it, maybe i'll find out

Comment: Is that possible to recreate issue on jsFiddle? In general, Highcharts is written in javascript, so doesn't matter if platform is x64 or x86.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I increased the GridLineWidth value to 2 (previously 1). Now it's work correct